# Is it possible to pipe a print statement in awk to multiple text files?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I think the question speaks for itself. I have two text files: file1 and file2. Here is a sample code with `awk` inside a bash script:

EDIT: I am using gnu awk

My Script:

```
val=3

awk 'if ("'$val'" == "3")
         print "Hello" >> "'$PWD/file1.txt'"
     else 
         print "Goodbye" #append to file1.txt and file2.txt
     '
```

I don't want something like this:
    val=3

```
awk 'if ("'$val'" == "3")
         print "Hello" >> "'$PWD/file1.txt'"
     else {
         print "Goodbye" >> "'$PWD/file1.txt'" 
         print "Goodbye" >> "'$PWD/file2.txt'"
     }'
```

I know that in bash you can use `tee` to pipe to multiple files. Can it be used in gnu awk? If so then how? Is there another way in gnu awk?

Comment: What is your awk flavor? GNU awk, or nawk, or ...

Comment: @SylvainLeroux GNU Awk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *GNU Awk* manual show an example of [how to simulate `tee` with `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Tee-Program.html). This might be a good starting point.

The basic idea will be to store the various output file names in an array -- and then to loop over this array to send the output on each file in its turn. In your case something *like that* (I type directly in SO -- you have to adapt/fix according to your needs, of course):

```
BEGIN {
  output[0] = "'$PWD/file1.txt'" 
  output[1] = "'$PWD/file1.txt'" 
  ...
}

{
    for (i in output)
        print "Goodbye!" >> output[i]
}
```

---

> I know that in bash you can use tee to pipe to multiple files. Can it be used in gnu awk?

If a non-awk only solution is acceptable, an other option will be to redirect some filedescriptor to `tee` in the outer bash scrip and then send output to that *fd* from `awk` when required. Here is a simple example:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 4<> >(tee file1.txt file2.txt)

awk '{ print NR;                        # send only to stdout
       print "READ:" $0 >> "/dev/fd/4"; # send to `tee`
}'
```

That produces:

```
sh$ (echo a; echo b) | ./a.sh
1
2
READ:a
READ:b
sh$ cat file1.txt 
READ:a
READ:b
sh$ cat file2.txt 
READ:a
READ:b
```

Answer (score 1):

Your awk script is wrong in the way it access the value of shell variables and you're putting the whole script in the condition section and so will get undesirable side effects if not syntax errors.

Your script:

```
val=3
awk 'if ("'$val'" == "3")
         print "Hello" >> "'$PWD/file1.txt'"
     else 
         print "Goodbye" #append to file1.txt and file2.txt
     '
```

should instead have been written as:

```
val=3
awk -v val="$val" -v pwd="${PWD}/" '{
     if (val == 3)
         print "Hello" >> (pwd "file1.txt")
     else 
         print "Goodbye" #append to file1.txt and file2.txt
}'
```

to be syntactically correct. To expand it to print to multiple files is:

```
val=3
awk -v val="$val" -v pwd="${PWD}/" '{
     if (val == 3) {
         print "Hello" >> (pwd "file1.txt")
     }
     else {
         print "Goodbye" >> (pwd "file1.txt")
         print "Goodbye" >> (pwd "file2.txt")
     }
}'
```

Or:

```
val=3
awk -v val="$val" -v pwd="${PWD}/" '
BEGIN { split("file1 file2",files) }
{
     if (val == 3)
         print "Hello" >> (pwd "file1.txt")
     else
         for (f in files)
             print "Goodbye" >> (pwd files[f] ".txt")
}'
```